# Swift : Animate SKEmitterNode

Tags: swift, animation, skemitternode

I am trying to create an explosion effect using `SKEmitterNode`, I followed some of this tutorial (http://www.waveworks.de/kill-your-characters-animating-explosions-with-skanimations-in-sprite-kit/), but it didn't seem to work. Here is what i have:

```
var superDabParticle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "superDabParticle.sks")

func setUpEmiterNode(){
    superDabParticle?.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    let superDabParticleEffectNode = SKEffectNode()
    superDabParticle?.zPosition = 1
    superDabParticle?.setScale(0)
    superDabParticleEffectNode.addChild(superDabParticle!)
    self.addChild(superDabParticleEffectNode)
}

func animateEmiterNode(){
    let birth = SKAction.runBlock { self.superDabParticle?.particleBirthRate = 0 }

    superDabParticle!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), SKAction.scaleBy(1.5, duration: 0.1), birth]))
}
```

So i need to call `setUpEmiterNode()` when the app first launches up, then when the user taps a button, call `animateEmiterNode` to have the particles fly from the bottom of the screen up to about 75% of the screen, then fall back down; giving a sort of explosion under water effect. Im using the `SPARK` emitter effect. If you know my issue or have any other ways that are better to do this, please assist!!

Comment: "It didn't seem to work" - Can you describe that more in detail ? :)